# get unused IP address

Tags: c#, networking

I need to get an available IP from the DHCP. I tried to get any ip address and start to ping the next until I reach one that doesn't respond.

```
public static IPAddress FindNextFree(this IPAddress address)
{
    IPAddress workingAddress = address;
    Ping pingSender = new Ping();

    while (true)
    {
        byte[] localBytes = workingAddress.GetAddressBytes();

        localBytes[3]++;
        if (localBytes[3] > 254)
            localBytes[3] = 1;

        workingAddress = new IPAddress(localBytes);

        if (workingAddress.Equals(address))
            throw new TimeoutException("Could not find free IP address");

        PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(workingAddress, 1000);
        if (reply.Status != IPStatus.Success)
        {
            return workingAddress;
        }
    }
}
```

However, sometimes the DHCP reserves special address for some computers, so I need to get an available ip address from the dhcp.
How can I implement that in C#?

Comment: It is the task of the dhcp server to ensure that no address given out will lead to a duplicate. So why on earth should the client try to solve this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this app that solve the problem
http://www.centrel-solutions.com/support/tools.aspx?feature=dhcpapi

Answer (score 3):

That is not the right way you are using it , 
you should request the DHCP server a new ip and then accept it , 
read about communicating with DHCP Server here

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol

Comment: yes how i can request ip from the DHCP.what i'm trying to do to get an unused ip in my network so how i can do that if i have all the privileges that i need, is there in interface that i can use ?

Comment: @AmjadAbdelrahman - Generally, requesting an IP address is handled on the OS level.  Why do you need to manually request one in your code?

Comment: @ Amjad Abdelrahman: you need some skills in network programming , google to find some ready to use code in C# to do these communication

Answer (score 3):

A client application cannot make a request to the DHCP server for all available addresses.

A DHCP server can only process the following messages from a client:

- DHCPDISCOVER
- DHCPREQUEST
- DHCPDECLINE
- DHCPRELEASE
- DHCPINFORM

Please see [RFC 2131 - Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2131.txt)for additional information.

If you are running [Windows DHCP server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/dd448608.aspx) and you have access to the box, you can use [Windows PowerShell Scripting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/powershell.aspx) to query the DHCP database.

Excerpt from [Weekend Scripter: Parsing the DHCP Database? No Way!](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/01/13/weekend-scripter-parsing-the-dhcp-database-no-way.aspx)

- **Summary:** Microsoft Scripting Guy, Ed Wilson, talks about a Windows PowerShell function from the DHCPServer module that permits parsing the DHCP database.

Comment: can't do that in WMI query?if yes what namespace can i use

Comment: There is no WMI interface to DHCP server itself.  [Dhcpcmd.exe tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/232213) can [export the contents of the DHCP database into a text file](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245126).